# Safe Area Misplaced in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I am having a strange issue that began when I started configuring the UI to work in landscape mode.

Several, but not all, of my view controllers are exhibiting a strange behavior with the Safe Area.

The Safe Area extends outside of the view. It is wrecking havoc with my UI.

[image: Stack Area Misplacement]

While this should not matter, I have checked all of my constraints to make sure I didn't have one where the Safe Area was set to be the size of something else.

I also cleaned the build folder as well as the project.

While I should not be able to change the Safe Area, bugs happen.

I am using Xcode Version 9.4 (9F1027a).

Any thoughts?

Update: It gets a bit stranger. It was the constraints, but I have no idea why. I deleted and redid them. The Safe Area was definitely changed as a result of the constraints. Now my question is, should I file a bug?

Answer (score 7):

Well, I have resolved the issue. I had to delete the constraints to the Safe Area, remove the Safe Area, set my constraints to the top level View, and once everything was correct, re-enable the Safe Area. I had to go back and edit a few constraints, but for the most part, it seems when you add the Safe Area back in, your constraints will switch to that.

[image: Safe Area Check Marks]

Just deleting and reimplementing the constraints did not fix the issue.

I hope this helps someone in the future who runs into it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the safe area is outside the view bounds is because one is changing the safe area bounds using auto layout.

See this example. I tried to specify that the trailing anchor of a view is supposed to equal the trailing anchor of the safe area. If one double-clicks the constraint, one can see that somehow the opposite is being defined. This causes the safe area to extend beyond the view bounds.

Solution is to click First Item and select Reverse first and second item.

[image]
[image]

Comment: y = mx + c or x = (y - c)/m it's same.

Comment: Actually it's because Xcode is a bug-ridden mess. The safe area is the safe area and no constraints are supposed to change it.